# Why do some ArcToolbox tools have red x over them?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arctoolbox, arcgis-license-manager

Why is it when you right-click to open some of the tools on the ArcToolbox, such as the TIN to Raster Tool for example, an image of a red x immediately appears over the tool icon?  The tool dialog then never opens.  What am I not understanding?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

The tool is not licensed.  This may be due to your ArcGIS license, or potentially an extension that is not turned on/licensed.  In the case of [TIN to Raster Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q900000077000000), it would be the 3D Analyst extension.

While [this article](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32201) is a little out of date, it may give you some ideas of what you should do in order to see if you can get it licensed.

Comment: Well here is a curveball for you. My ArcGIS desktop administrator says the 3D Analyst Extension is authorized. I also have the extension checked (enabled) when running ArcGIS.  The licenses I received from ESRI are the single-use for home variety. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Is your 3D concurrent/floating? My recollection is that this will only be accessible to a concurrent/floating ArcGIS for Desktop core product.

Comment: Good point @Polygeo.  You cannot mix single use ArcGIS Desktop licenses with concurrent use extensions, or vice-versa.

Comment: My ArcGIS Administrator says "ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced (Single Use)" across the top so I am assuming all the installed products are single use. The provision file I got from ESRI has a "prvc" extension and codes in it that all start with "ESU".

Comment: Just to add to this issue it seems as though its only the items in the 3D Analyst Tools that are affected by this. All other extension tools open normally. I reinstalled 3D Analyst extension - same issue - red x appears by all tools after a right click.